# Из-за чего не работают расширения для браузера Гугл Хром?

Tags: google-chrome, расширения

Установил себе для браузера расширение типа линейки и прочего, открываю index.html в браузере, но расширения не работают, причем если открываю какие-то сайты всё работает отлично, а в индексе даже не нажимаются.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dimensions/baocaagndhipibgklemoalmkljaimfdj?hl=ru
ссылка на расширение

Comment: Может приведете код этого индекса?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, любой код ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что расширения не работают с протоколом `file://`. Запусти какой-нибудь сервер и открывай страницу по `http`.